# Problem on Train Time

Tags: education

Two trains 137 metres and 163 metres long run together at speed of 42 kmph and 48kmph. In what time will they clear of each other from the moment they meet?

I do not understand the statement properly "In what time will they clear of each other from the moment they meet?"

Can anyone explain with illustration ?

The solution goes as :
Relative speed of trains = 90 kmph (25 m/s)

Time taken by them to pass each other= time taken to cover (137+163) m at 25m/sec

Why did we put time taken to cover (137+163). Probably the question gets me confused without illustration..

There is also this formula:

If two trains of length a metres and b metres are moving in the same direction at u m/s and v m/s then time taken by faster train to cross the slower train =(a+b)/(u-v) m/s

Why am i getting a wrong answer using this formula ?

any explaination would be appreciated. please help

Answer (score 1):

The moment when the trains meet is when the front of the faster train is aligned with the end of the slower train. The faster train will now start passing the slower train. The faster train will have cleared the slower train when its end has passed the front of the slower train.

[image]

> $d=300m$, $v=25ms^{-1}$ , $t=12 s$.

Comment: Can you please explain ?